# Periodic work requests still running even when constraints are not met

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager API (version 2.4.0) to create simple periodic running tasks. Here is the worker class

```
class BackupWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting worker")

    makeNotification(
            "Preparing worker",
            applicationContext
    )

    sleep() //simulate long running task

    for(i in 0..20) {
        makeNotification(
                "Firing update $i",
                applicationContext,
                true
        )
        sleep()
    }


    makeNotification(
            "Worker complete",
            applicationContext
    )

    Log.i(TAG, "Finishing backup worker")

    Result.success()
 }
}
```

And the work request is set up as follows

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                            .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true).build();

PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackupWorker.class,
                    15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .build();

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("tag_worker",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            workRequest);
```

The work request is being correctly picked up by the OS. However, if I turn Wi-Fi off whilst running, it doesn't stop and continues to run what's inside `doWork()` which in fact contradicts the whole purpose of this API.

Is there anything missing here? Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `sleep()`? If you are using `CoroutineWorker`, the proper way to simulate a delay is using Coroutine's `delay` method.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did change it to ```delay``` method. It is still running when Wi-Fi is off